# Why is the start tab page of the Tor Browser empty?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

[image: Screenshot from Tor Browser]

Why isn't there any information on the newtab page in the Tor Browser, like an FAQ, atlas, tests of anonymity for browser, News/RSS reader, etc.?

What is the advantage of not showing information like this by default? Why is it empty?

Comment: Voting to close as it's opinion-based. If you've suggestions, you should create a ticket on https://trac.torproject.org.

Comment: It is question. Is there any logic in void?

Comment: And the answer is "because nobody put anything there".  I'm not sure how useful that is. :)

Comment: Why not answer this question from a security perspective (explain how Tor browser doesn't maintain state between sessions)? I think there are legit answers nto this question which aren't opinion based (the question could be modified a bit to be more useful)

Comment: @SamWhited That page doesn't require statefulness. You could place static, Tor related links thee.

Comment: @SamWhited - Good suggestion. I made a suggested edit to help improve the post.

Comment: This question made me smile.

Comment: Why is there something rather than nothing? Oh no, I meant, why is there nothing rather than something?

Answer (score 5):

It's empty, because no one has put something there. Maybe also because someone never suggested it.

Filling it up with links to Tor by default wouldn't be a wise choice either, I think. Having it empty has greater chances of staying empty than filling it with Tor related links. If it was filled up with Tor related links by default, users would more likely fill it up with their own content. They might store links, which contain an ID and since this preview tab might get prefetched (downloaded before clicking on it, so it can later be displayed faster), it might be bad for anonymity.

Other users use bookmarks as they are easier to handle.

Sometimes less code and fewer changes to software (the Tor Browser is based on Firefox) can be more easily maintained by its producer. Such changes need to be thoroughly thought through. Are there any consequences from a anonymity/privacy standpoint? Since this request seems so unpopular, it might have been simpler to forget about it and leave it as it is right now (empty).